# Type class instance head is invalid due to use of type (row type)

Tags: purescript

I need to define a simple typeclass and instance for record type:

```
class Codable param where
  getCodec :: Codec param


type Obj = { id :: String }

instance Codable Obj where
  getCodec = objCodec
```

Though when defining instance for a record type I get the error:

```
 Type class instance head is invalid due to use of type

    ( id :: string
    )

 All types appearing in instance declarations must be of the form T a_1 .. a_n, where each type a_i is of the same form, unless the type is fully determined by other type class arguments via functional dependencies.
```

But the message sounds quite cryptic to me. Can someone elaborate, and what to do in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PureScript just doesn't support instances for rows, that's it.

And in case you didn't know, the curly-brace syntax is syntactic sugar for applying the `Record` constructor to a type row, i.e. `{ id :: String }` is equivalent to `Record ( id :: String )`.

The usual workaround is to wrap your record in a `newtype`:

```
newtype Obj = Obj { id :: String }

instance Codable Obj where ...
```

Or, alternatively, if you really wanted to provide codecs for all kinds of records (kind of what `purescript-argonaut` does), you could convert the row to `RowList` and then do type-level matching on it. This is kind of high-power, high-difficulty technique, and I am not prepared to explain it thoroughly right now, but [here's an example](https://github.com/paluh/purescript-undefined-is-not-a-problem/blob/2c29d97bf5ec270d4b8bc7f6b5321e4985eaa5e0/src/Data/Undefined/NoProblem/Closed.purs#L12), and [here's another one](https://github.com/collegevine/purescript-elmish/blob/8f9c5efa2d4f9a6b9d9dab3d00b558bdc4a5f727/src/Elmish/Foreign.purs#L167-L183). And [here's the same thing used in `purescript-argonaut`](https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-argonaut-codecs/blob/b0a041d92bfd548e2cd793cc7c02363464325a13/src/Data/Argonaut/Decode/Class.purs#L97-L134).

Comment: Thanks! At least I'm now can be sure that there is not an easy way that I just didn't know about.